# C# boxing enum error with generics

Tags: c#, generics, enums, icomparablet

I don't understand what is going on here...

I've got the following error:
*The type `'TestApp.TestVal'` cannot be used as type parameter `'T'` in the generic type or method `'TestApp.SomeClass<T>'`. There is no boxing conversion from `'TestApp.TestVal'` to `'System.IComparable<TestApp.TestVal>'`.*

This error happens for the following code:

```
public enum TestVal
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

public class SomeClass<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T Stored
    {
        get
        {
            return storedval;
        }
        set
        {
            storedval = value;
        }
    }
    private T storedval;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Error is on the next line
        SomeClass<TestVal> t = new SomeClass<TestVal>(); 
    }
}
```

Since the enum is an `int` by default and int's implement the `IComparable<int>` interface it seems like there shouldn't be an error....

Comment: int's implement IComparable<int> but that doesn't mean RandomEnumType implements IComparable<RandomEnumType>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure whether it is sensible to use `IComparable<T>` with an enum... `IEquatable<T>`, sure - but comparison?

As a safer alternative; rather than mandate the `IComparable<T>` with the generic constraint, perhaps use `Comparer<T>.Default` inside the class. This has the advantage of supporting `IComparable<T>` and `IComparable` - and it means you have less constraints to propagate.

For example:

```
public class SomeClass<T> { // note no constraint
    public int ExampleCompareTo(T other) {
        return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(Stored, other);
    }
    ... [snip]
}
```

This works fine with the enum:

```
SomeClass<TestVal> t = new SomeClass<TestVal>();
t.Stored = TestVal.First;
int i = t.ExampleCompareTo(TestVal.Second); // -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible alternate solution to my problem. The actual code is very deep in a test framework that needs to handle just about any type of test data. I'll have to do some more investigation but it seems like your code might be a better way to deal with the compare in my generic objects....

Answer (score 5):

Enums do not derive from System.Int32s - they derive from System.Enum, which doesn't implement `IComparable<int>` (it does implement `IComparable`, though).

Although an enum's underlying value is an int by default, the enum itself isn't. Thus, there is no conversion between the two.

Comment: (I fixed the markdown - and then went crazy and edited your answer instead of my own! Fixed now; sorry about that...)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helps. It also makes me wonder if I will have the same kind of problem with structs....

Answer (score 1):

Enum doesn't implement `IComparable<T>`, but it does implement `IComparable`.  So an enum can be the T in a where clause like:

```
    where T : IComparable
```

but this gives an error:

```
    where T : IComparable<T>
```

And then I suppose you'd like SomeClass to be comparable.  To do that, it would have to implement IComparable itself.

Here's an example of both (using a public member to keep the code simple):

```
public class SomeClass<T>
    : IComparable<SomeClass<T>>
    where T : IComparable
{
    public T storedval;

    public int CompareTo(SomeClass<T> other)
    {
        return storedval.CompareTo(other.storedval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# enums implement `IComparable`, but not the generic `IComparable<T>`.  I'm not sure why this is, but maybe you could switch to the non-generic `IComparable` in your where clause.