# How can I create a JsonPatchDocument from comparing two c# objects?

Tags: c#, json-patch

Given I have two c# objects of the same type, I want to compare them to create a JsonPatchDocument.

I have a StyleDetail class defined like this:

```
public class StyleDetail
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal OriginalPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public bool Wishlist { get; set; }
        public List<string> Attributes { get; set; }
        public ColourList Colours { get; set; }
        public SizeList Sizes { get; set; }
        public ResultPage<Style> Related { get; set; }
        public ResultPage<Style> Similar { get; set; }
        public List<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
        public int StoreStock { get; set; }
        public StyleDetail()
        {
            Attributes = new List<string>();
            Colours = new ColourList();
            Sizes = new SizeList();
            Promotions = new List<Promotion>();
        }
    }
```

if I have two StyleDetail objects

```
StyleDetail styleNew = db.GetStyle(123);
StyleDetail styleOld = db.GetStyle(456);
```

I now want to create a JsonPatchDocument so I can send the differences to my REST API... How to do this??

```
JsonPatchDocument patch = new JsonPatchDocument();
// Now I want to populate patch with the differences between styleNew and styleOld - how?
```

in javascript, there is a library to do this https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfc6902

> Calculate diff between two objects:
>
> rfc6902.createPatch({first: 'Chris'}, {first: 'Chris', last:
>   'Brown'});
>
> ```
> [ { op: 'add', path: '/last', value: 'Brown' } ]
> ```

but I am looking for a c# implementation

Comment: I know this is a bit old now ... but did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm looking for the exact same thing!

Comment: You could use reflection to iterate through the properties and compare them. See this question for an example of iterating properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-sharp-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's abuse the fact that your classes are serializable to JSON!
Here's a first attempt at a patch creator that doesn't care about your actual object, only about the JSON representation of that object.

```
public static JsonPatchDocument CreatePatch(object originalObject, object modifiedObject)
{
    var original = JObject.FromObject(originalObject);
    var modified = JObject.FromObject(modifiedObject);

    var patch = new JsonPatchDocument();
    FillPatchForObject(original, modified, patch, "/");

    return patch;
}

static void FillPatchForObject(JObject orig, JObject mod, JsonPatchDocument patch, string path)
{
    var origNames = orig.Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    var modNames = mod.Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();

    // Names removed in modified
    foreach (var k in origNames.Except(modNames))
    {
        var prop = orig.Property(k);
        patch.Remove(path + prop.Name);
    }

    // Names added in modified
    foreach (var k in modNames.Except(origNames))
    {
        var prop = mod.Property(k);
        patch.Add(path + prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }

    // Present in both
    foreach (var k in origNames.Intersect(modNames))
    {
        var origProp = orig.Property(k);
        var modProp = mod.Property(k);

        if (origProp.Value.Type != modProp.Value.Type)
        {
            patch.Replace(path + modProp.Name, modProp.Value);
        }
        else if (!string.Equals(
                        origProp.Value.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None),
                        modProp.Value.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)))
        {
            if (origProp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                // Recurse into objects
                FillPatchForObject(origProp.Value as JObject, modProp.Value as JObject, patch, path + modProp.Name +"/");
            }
            else
            {
                // Replace values directly
                patch.Replace(path + modProp.Name, modProp.Value);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var patch = CreatePatch(
    new { Unchanged = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, Changed = "1", Removed = "1" },
    new { Unchanged = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, Changed = "2", Added = new { x = "1" } });

// Result of JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patch)
[
  {
    "path": "/Removed",
    "op": "remove"
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "x": "1"
    },
    "path": "/Added",
    "op": "add"
  },
  {
    "value": "2",
    "path": "/Changed",
    "op": "replace"
  }
]
```

Comment: By the way - you can use the exact same code to diff to JSON strings as well, just create JObjects from the strings and then call `FillPatchForObject`

Comment: Thank you! Big help. But it does not work correctly if we change "Colours", for example, in the "StyleDetail" class.

Comment: Is "StyleDetail" being serialized correctly to JSON, if you serialize it directly? Otherwise, my method won't work. Can you give the definition of StyleDetail, and two example objects that give the error?

Comment: The difference here is arrays. I don't attempt to handle arrays in a nice way, I just replace the whole array if there is a difference.

It would not be hard to compare element by element, but imagine if you have an array of 700 elements, and you remove element 0. Detecting these kinds of changes are complicated. The naive way of comparing arrays, would end up "replacing" elements 0-698, and removing element 699.

Comment: it works perfectly when all the properties are object. But if a property is a array, the patch will replace the entire array instead, which is redundant and in some case affect the performance.

Comment: here is a updated version that supports replacing array element instead of the whole array https://gist.github.com/yww325/b71563462cb5b5f2ea29e0143634bebe

Answer (score 0):

You could use my DiffAnalyzer. It's based on reflection and you can configure the depth you want to analyze.

https://github.com/rcarubbi/Carubbi.DiffAnalyzer

```
var before = new User { Id = 1, Name="foo"};
var after= new User  { Id = 2, Name="bar"};
var analyzer = new DiffAnalyzer();
var results = analyzer.Compare(before, after);
```

Comment: Does this return a json patch?

Comment: no, you still have to convert the results into a JsonPatch. You will have all the diffs though.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [this](https://github.com/khalidsalomao/SimpleHelpers.Net/blob/master/docs/objectdiffpatch.md)

You can install using NuGet, see SimpleHelpers.ObjectDiffPatch at NuGet.org

```
PM> Install-Package SimpleHelpers.ObjectDiffPatch
```

Use:

```
StyleDetail styleNew = new StyleDetail() { Id = "12", Code = "first" };
StyleDetail styleOld = new StyleDetail() { Id = "23", Code = "second" };
var diff = ObjectDiffPatch.GenerateDiff (styleOld , styleNew );

// original properties values
Console.WriteLine (diff.OldValues.ToString());

// updated properties values
Console.WriteLine (diff.NewValues.ToString());
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are manually adding the items to replace in code, not generating a patch document by comparing two objects

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: This project does a diff, but it does not produce a JsonPatchDocument